# Java: Is there a way to know 'how' close you are to a number?

Tags: java, random, numbers

I'm doing a random number guessing game (generate a random number between 1 and 25, user has 5 tries to guess the number). I'm required to say things like "You're really close to the number" or "You're really far off the number" according to how close the number the user entered is to the randomly generated number.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "close"?

Comment: I guess if the random number is 25, and the user introduces a number from 20-24 it would say "You're very close", if 10-19 "You're a bit far off the number" and 0-9 "you're very far off the number". I wanted to know if there was some kind of method for this or if I just have to do a If with the formulas+validations?

Comment: Then do that. If they enter a number between 0 and 9, print ...

Comment: Get the absolute value of the difference between the number? `int diff = Math.abs(n1 - n2)` then all you need to do is `if` statements on `diff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose one way to do it would be to take the absolute value (`Math.abs(...)`) of the user's guess subtracted from the randomly generated number, and then just use an `if`-`else` ladder to determine what you want to print out based on that number and your definition of "close"

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference using  `int diff = Math.abs(n1 - n2)` and then just do and if else chain to print what you need to